# What exactly is the Clojure REPL? What is the technology behind it?

Tags: clojure

I know what the Clojure Repl *does* and how it is useful, but I do not have any information on how the internals of it works. Is it a program running in the JVM? How does the internals of a repl work?

Comment: Did you try to look for REPL first ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Comment: like I said, I know what it is and what it does, but not the underlying technology and how it **works**

Comment: It would be best suited to the project's mailing list.

Comment: @jmargolisvt this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 9):

The technology behind it:

1. the tiny Java entry point:

   https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/jvm/clojure/main.java
2. the actual implementation of the REPL written in Clojure:

   https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/main.clj

The links are to the 1.7.0 versions of the files, that being the most recent stable release as of this writing.

To summarize what these do, `clojure.main` is a tiny Java class with a `main` method that serves as the entry point to the REPL. (So, it's just a standard Java program.) That `main` method accepts any arguments and hands them off to a function in the `clojure.main` Clojure namespace (using a few simple calls to methods in the `clojure.lang.RT` class which implements some core details of the Clojure runtime to get at the function in question – well, strictly speaking the Var that holds the function). Then the said function calls code that actually Reads user input, Evaluates it, Prints out the result and Loops around to the read more input again, until terminated by <kbd>C-d</kbd> or some other method, with various complications like setting up some Var bindings and such (to allow user control over some aspects of the REPL's operation and certain compiler settings).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. So the repl is embedded into the main program? Does it use something like JRebel to load classes into the running JVM? A new function defined at the repl needs to be compiled to byte code and I assume somehow 'injected' into the running JVM? Is that a separate JVM?

Comment: The details of this are way out of scope for a comment, but the JDK itself provides an elaborate mechanism for loading new classes at runtime (for a start see this page: [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)). The Clojure compiler compiles various Clojure constructs into classes, using a lot of custom logic and the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) library for the lowest-level details, and then loads the classes. Optionally those classes can also be emitted to files – this is known as AOT compilation and makes loading them in future JVM instances faster.